# Getting the error "cannot assign function to call" when computing derivatives with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

This code is a derivative code for a Taylor expansion that is 5 derivatives long. So `ds(i)` is supposed to replace its zero valued variables with the new `x` values (the derivative values). I keep getting   the error "cannot assign function to call"

```
def derivatives(f, x, a, n):
    f = f(x)
    x = var
    a = 1.0
    n = 5
    ds = np.zeros(n)
    exp = f(x)
    for i in range(n):
        exp = sp.diff(exp,x)
        ds(i) = exp.replace(x, a)
    return ds
```

Comment: What is `ds(i) = exp.replace(x, a)` supposed to do? Do you mean `ds[i] = exp.replace(x, a)`?

Comment: This code is a derivative code for a taylor expansion that is 5 derivatives long. So ds(i) is supposed to replace its  zero valued variables with the new x values (the derivative values)

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `ds[i]`, not `ds(i)`. Square brackers for indexing vs round parentheses for function calls. That said, the code has other issues, from undefined `var` to using a NumPy array (?) to store SymPy objects. In general, it's advisable to keep in mind that SymPy works primarily with **expressions** not with **functions**. Expressions do not "take arguments", they are not like callable functions in Python.

And all of this is unnecessary, because SymPy computes n-th derivative on its own. Example, the 5th derivative of exp(2*x) at 0:

```
x = sp.symbols('x')
f = sp.exp(2*x)     # an expression, not a function
n = 5
a = 0
print(f.diff(x, n).subs(x, a))    # take derivative n times, then plug a for x
```

prints 32. Or, if you want a Taylor expansion up to and including `x**n`:

```
print(f.series(x, a, n + 1))
```

prints `1 + 2*x + 2*x**2 + 4*x**3/3 + 2*x**4/3 + 4*x**5/15 + O(x**6)`.